# Grails could not find matching constructor for: somiti.JointMember(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am using grails 2.4.2. I have a domain as JointMemberInvestment where I have an instance of JointMember class. But when I want to save the data it gives me the following error:

> Could not find matching constructor for: somiti.JointMember(java.lang.String).

Here are my attempts below.

My domain class:

```
    class JointMemberInvestment {

    JointMember jointMember
    int investAmount
    Date investDate

    static mapping = {
        table('joint_member_investment')
        version defaultValue: 0
    }

    static constraints = {
        investAmount(nullable: false, blank: false)
        investDate(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

My controller save method:

```
@Transactional
def save(JointMemberInvestment jointMemberInvestmentInstance) {
    if (jointMemberInvestmentInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    String investDate = params.investDate;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = sdf.parse(investDate);
    java.sql.Date sqlInvestDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

    jointMemberInvestmentInstance.investDate = sqlInvestDate
    jointMemberInvestmentInstance.jointMember = JointMember.get(Long.parseLong(params.jointMemberId))        

    if (jointMemberInvestmentInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond jointMemberInvestmentInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }

    jointMemberInvestmentInstance.save flush: true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'jointMemberInvestment.label', default: 'JointMemberInvestment'), jointMemberInvestmentInstance.id])
            redirect jointMemberInvestmentInstance
        }
        '*' { respond jointMemberInvestmentInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

Comment: In short no cos you have `JointMember.get(` followed by `hasErrors()` so anything you wish to add to the code. Adding snippets of the code specifically where the problem does not relate to will not help resolve your issue. More specifically when it throws `Could not find matching constructor ` does it give any further clues such as controllers/services and line numbers ? half of actual error code and half of actual code well no - unless we are sitting at your end

Comment: @vahid thanks for your reply. No other errors are given. It shows during save. no error at console at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
jointMemberInvestmentInstance.investDate = sqlInvestDate
    jointMemberInvestmentInstance.jointMember = JointMember.get(Long.parseLong(params.jointMemberId))        

bindData(jointMemberInvestmentInstance, params, [exclude:['JointMember']])

    if (jointMemberInvestmentInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond jointMemberInvestmentInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }
```

May be this will help you.